# Baddly drawn canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to draw a line starting on a given point and crossing two other points. To do this, I get the x and y coordinates of these points, and then I drawn. This is what my code should do :

JS:

```
function getPosition(element)
{
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;
    var e = document.getElementById(element);
    while (e.offsetParent != undefined && e.offsetParent != null)
    {
        left += e.offsetLeft + (e.clientLeft != null ? e.clientLeft : 0);
        top += e.offsetTop + (e.clientTop != null ? e.clientTop : 0);
        e = e.offsetParent;
    }
    return new Array(left,top);
}

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var point1 = getPosition('firstGalaxy');
var point2 = getPosition('secondGalaxy');
var point3 = getPosition('lastGalaxy');
console.log(point1);
console.log(point2);
console.log(point3);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(point1[0], point1[1]);
ctx.lineTo(point2[0], point2[1]);
ctx.lineTo(point3[0], point3[1]);
ctx.stroke(2);
ctx.closePath();
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="position:absolute;" class="constellation">
```

The values printed in my console seems to be good, but the result is a mess.
Here is a picture of the result

[image]

The grey square on the right is the result, and the red line is what I would like to get.
I don't even know why I get a square because I am using "stroke()".

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your getPosition function is unnecessary. You can get absolute values for the element's position using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect).

Answer (score 0):

Change ctx.stroke(2) to ctx.stroke(), add ctx.strokeStyle="red" to change the line's color.  And, add `</canvas>` to the HTML.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="position:absolute;" class="constellation"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
function getPosition(element)
{
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;
    var e = document.getElementById(element);
    while (e.offsetParent != undefined && e.offsetParent != null)
    {
        left += e.offsetLeft + (e.clientLeft != null ? e.clientLeft : 0);
        top += e.offsetTop + (e.clientTop != null ? e.clientTop : 0);
        e = e.offsetParent;
    }
    return new Array(left,top);
}

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var point1 = getPosition('firstGalaxy');
var point2 = getPosition('secondGalaxy');
var point3 = getPosition('lastGalaxy');
console.log(point1);
console.log(point2);
console.log(point3);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(point1[0], point1[1]);
ctx.lineTo(point2[0], point2[1]);
ctx.lineTo(point3[0], point3[1]);
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: If this still does not work, it is probably because the positions are not correctly set.  If that is the case, please post all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

A few directions :

1) to debug, be sure your points are at the right place by drawing them using something like :

```
function drawPoint(ctx, pt, color, pointSize ) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color || '#F88';
    var pointSize = pointSize || 2;
    var x = pt[0], y=pt[1];
    ctx.fillRect(x - pointSize/2, y-pointSize/2, pointSize, pointSize);
}
```

2) use getBoundingClientRect to retrieve a control position with maximum reliability.

```
function getPosition(element, provideCenter)
{
    var elementBoundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var point = [elementBoundingRect.left, elementBoundingRect.top];
    if (provideCenter) {
        point[0] += (elementBoundingRect.right  - elementBoundingRect.left) /2;
        point[1] += (elementBoundingRect.bottom - elementBoundingRect.top ) /2;
    }
    return point;
}
```

3) Be sure the canvas covers all the screen and do simple unit tests on various parts of the screen using getPosition and drawPoint on several visible html items.

Edit : The code provided in 1) is good. If in doubt, look at this test here : 
http://jsbin.com/aDimoJI/1/
You must be able to draw points anywhere before going anywhere further.
Be sure your canvas is on top of everything else for this test, so you'll have to handle this issue...

Comment: Thank you.
I tried both of your functions. The first doesn't draw anything on my screen, but I really think my coordinates are good. Maybe the drawn points are hidden behind an element, because of my parallax system.

The second return an error in my console : "TypeError: element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function".

And for the canvas to cover all the screen, must I encompass my whole page in <canvas></canvas> ?

I'll continue testing, thank you !